# Apache web server hangs when calling stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, apache, stored-procedures

I am writing a PHP based website.

My spec :

- XAMPP version 1.7.4
- Windows Vista
- Firefox 3.6
- AdoDB layer

I have a MySQL database with one table and one stored procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_get_password`(IN `p_user_name` VARCHAR(10))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN SELECT user_password FROM users WHERE user_name = p_user_name LIMIT 1; END
```

When I trying to call the stored procedure :

```
$res = $db -> Execute ("call user_get_password('" . check_marks( $_POST['user_name'] ) . "');");
```

the Apache web server crashes and stops.

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong with my code ?

The apache error.log is almost empty :

```
[Mon Oct 10 13:09:59 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Oct 10 13:09:59 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:15 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:15 2011] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:17 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:17 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:17 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 13664
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:18 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Oct 10 13:12:18 2011] [notice] Digest: done
```

EDIT : I've founded an error log in the 'windows system log' :

> A hibát okozó alkalmazás: httpd.exe, verzió: 2.2.17.0, időbélyeg:
>   0x4cbbe9e8, a hibát okozó modul: php5ts.dll, verziószám: 5.3.5.0,
>   időbélyeg: 0x4d26013e, kivételkód: 0xc0000005, hiba pozíciója:
>   0x00081047, folyamatazonosító: 0x17b8, az alkalmazás indításának
>   időpontja: 0x01cc873e337fb7c0.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the apache error log in `%XAMPPDIR%\apache\logs\error.log`?

Comment: Do you really need to use a STORED Procedure?!

Comment: No, I've modified to 'pure' sql query, and now it's working. Thanks !